# Alternative of mocking a static method present in some jar

Tags: java, junit, mockito, powermock

I know that if I need to mock a static method, this indicates that my design has some issue, but in my case this does not seem to be a design issue.

```
BundleContext bundleContext = FrameworkUtil.getBundle(ConfigService.class).getBundleContext();
```

Here FrameworkUtil is a class present in an api jar. Using it in code cant be a design issue.

my problem here is while running this line

```
FrameworkUtil.getBundle(ConfigService.class);
```

returns null So my question, is there any way by which I can replace that null at runtime 
I am using Mockito framewrok and my project does not allow me to use powermock.

if I use

```
doReturn(bundle).when(FrameworkUtil.class)
```

in this way getBundle method is not visible since its a static method.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are correct that is not a design issue on your part. Without PowerMock, your options become a bit murkier, though.

I would suggest creating a non-static wrapper for the FrameworkUtil class that you can inject and mock.

**Update:** (David Wallace)

So you add a new class to your application, something like this

```
public class UtilWrapper {
    public Bundle getBundle(Class<?> theClass) {
        return FrameworkUtil.getBundle(theClass);
    }
}
```

This class is so simple that you don't need to unit test it.  As a general principle, you should only EVER write unit tests for methods that have some kind of logic to them - branching, looping or exception handling.  One-liners should NOT be unit tested.

Now, within your application code, add a field of type `UtilWrapper`, and a setter for it, to every class that currently calls `FrameworkUtil.getBundle`.  Add this line to the construtor of each such class

```
utilWrapper = new UtilWrapper();
```

And replace every call to `FrameworkUtil.getBundle` with `utilWrapper.getBundle`.

Now in your test, you make a mock `UtilWrapper` and stub it to return whatever `Bundle` you like.

```
when(mockUtilWrapper.getBundle(ConfigService.class)).thenReturn(someBundleYouMade);
```

and for the class that you're testing, call `setUtilWrapper(mockUtilWrapper)` or whatever.  You don't need this last step if you're using `@InjectMocks`.

Now your test should all hang together, but using your mocked `UtilWrapper` instead of the one that relies on `FrameworkUtil`.

Comment: This is the correct way of doing it.  +1.  ankit, if you need more help to see how to do this, post a comment here and I'll edit @Dave's answer to include some actual code.

Comment: I use powermock to handle this with a spy and refactor my code. eg: instead of: int count = StaticClass.getCount(); I do: int count = getCount(); and in "getCount" method is a single line that calls "StaticClass.getCount()". Using a "spy" the non-static "getCount" never actually gets called, the "StaticClass.getCount();" line never gets executed.

Comment: Then maybe you should post a separate answer, detailing your way of doing it.

Comment: @DavidWallace if I create a wrapper for that class then also I need to call that static method and will endup getting same issue. So it would be great if you give me some working code. or just a hint of that

Comment: @TitiWangsaBinDamhore I cant use powermock in my project as I am not the one who makes decision on which framework to be used. :(

Comment: @ankit, but the next person to find this question on Stack OVerflow _might_ be permitted to use PowerMock.  So I think that there is value in TitiWangsaBinDamhore posting an answer, even though it won't help _you_.

Answer (score 2):

unit test

```
package x;

import static org.junit.Assert.*;

import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.mockito.Mockito;

public class GunTest {

  @Before
  public void setUp() throws Exception {
  }

  @Test
  public void testFireTrue() {
    final Gun unit = Mockito.spy(new Gun());
    Mockito.doReturn(5).when(unit).getCount();
    assertTrue(unit.fire2());
  }

  @Test
  public void testFireFalse() {
    final Gun unit = Mockito.spy(new Gun());
    Mockito.doReturn(15).when(unit).getCount();
    assertFalse(unit.fire2());
  }

}
```

the unit:
fire calls the static method directly,
fire2 factors out the static call to a protected method:

```
package x;

public class Gun {

  public boolean fire() {
    if (StaticClass.getCount() > 10) {
      return false;
    }
    else {
      return true;
    }
  }

  public boolean fire2() {
    if (getCount() > 10) {
      return false;
    }
    else {
      return true;
    }
  }

  protected int getCount() {
    return StaticClass.getCount();
  }
}
```

Comment: pure Mockito without Powermock dealing with static method calls.

Comment: seems you are near to the answer can you change this code according to my case

Comment: If the OP is only using the one static method inside this particular class, your solution is elegant (+1 for that). If that same method or other static methods from the same class are used elsewhere, the pattern needs to be repeated, which is generally a hint at bad design.

Comment: I agree with Dave. we would end up with multiple classes with the same method name and same method body. Sonarqube would complain. DRY.

Comment: you have not shown a code to call any static method and the point remains the same @TitiWangsaBinDamhore